# Skill getting End when user responded while audio file playing

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

After Using audio in Alexa skill when Audio start and in between audio user responded and New intent triggers skill getting closed not triggering required intent?

User : "Invoked skill"

Alexa : "Welcome Message"

User : "Responded and skill flow start"

Alexa : "Any question ? - < Playing Audio >"

User : "Start giving answer....."

While Audio is playing as user responded skill ends

Playing Audio file with SSML audio tag after speak output message.

```
speak_output = f" <speak> Please listen this audio clip: <audio 
                    src='{mp3_url}'/> </speak>"
```

How can i keep session live when user responded in between audio and the intent i want to trigger should be executed..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7EXw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't understand your question.

In your example, the user needs to prefix their answer with the wake word in order to interrupt the audio being played.  This should trigger the intent associated with the answer utterance (assuming your interaction model has been correctly setup to capture user answers).

Comment: I see from the Alexa dev forum that you've solved the problem and that the issue was not setting the "shouldEndSession" response property to "false".